# IDEA 14. Decompile my own classes(from output directory)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, decompiling

I want to look at the code generated from my own sources but it seems that IDEA doesn't decompile them using new fernflower plugin using *IntelliJ API Decompiler* instead.

At least I have header comment

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available
```

and methods like that: `public void update() { /* compiled code */ }`

At the same time, in external library(for example JDK), i see normal header and decompiled code.

```
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
```

I can make decompiler works, if I compile code to jar and add it to some module, but it's doesn't look like a normal solution.

Can I make IDEA decompile any class file using fernflower?

**EDIT:** While opening file I get an exception in IDEA log file. See snippet.

```html
<pre>
2015-02-13 19:16:29,991 [119281666]   WARN - l.compiled.ClassFileDecompiler - decompiler: class org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.IdeaDecompiler
com.intellij.psi.compiled.ClassFileDecompilers$Light$CannotDecompileException: org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.IdeaLogger$InternalException: Method <init> (Ljava/util/HashMap;)V couldn't be decompiled.
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.IdeaDecompiler.getText(IdeaDecompiler.java:162)
 at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClassFileDecompiler.decompile(ClassFileDecompiler.java:57)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.LoadTextUtil.loadText(LoadTextUtil.java:364)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileDocumentManagerImpl.getDocument(FileDocumentManagerImpl.java:167)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.text.PsiAwareTextEditorProvider.createEditorAsync(PsiAwareTextEditorProvider.java:58)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl4(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:778)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl3(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:736)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$8.run(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:716)
 at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:117)
 at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
 at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:85)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileImpl2(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:713)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openFileWithProviders(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:654)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.ex.FileEditorManagerEx.openFile(FileEditorManagerEx.java:146)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$14.run(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1071)
 at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
 at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
 at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:85)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.openEditor(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1067)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.OpenFileDescriptor.navigateInAnyFileEditor(OpenFileDescriptor.java:152)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.OpenFileDescriptor.navigateInEditor(OpenFileDescriptor.java:138)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.OpenFileDescriptor.navigateInEditorOrNativeApp(OpenFileDescriptor.java:134)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.OpenFileDescriptor.navigate(OpenFileDescriptor.java:121)
 at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementBase.navigate(PsiElementBase.java:197)
 at com.intellij.codeInsight.navigation.NavigationUtil.openFileWithPsiElement(NavigationUtil.java:167)
 at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.navigate(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:207)
 at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractPsiBasedNode.navigate(AbstractPsiBasedNode.java:217)
 at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.PsiFileNode.navigate(PsiFileNode.java:132)
 at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigate(OpenSourceUtil.java:53)
 at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.openSourcesFrom(OpenSourceUtil.java:31)
 at com.intellij.util.EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler$TreeMouseListener.processDoubleClick(EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler.java:130)
 at com.intellij.util.EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler$TreeMouseListener.onDoubleClick(EditSourceOnDoubleClickHandler.java:122)
 at com.intellij.ui.DoubleClickListener.onClick(DoubleClickListener.java:30)
 at com.intellij.ui.ClickListener$1.mouseReleased(ClickListener.java:73)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:273)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
 at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree.processMouseEvent(Tree.java:421)
 at com.intellij.ide.dnd.aware.DnDAwareTree.processMouseEvent(DnDAwareTree.java:53)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
 at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:748)
 at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:573)
 at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:384)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.IdeaLogger$InternalException: Method <init> (Ljava/util/HashMap;)V couldn't be decompiled.
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.IdeaLogger.writeMessage(IdeaLogger.java:44)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.rels.ClassWrapper.init(ClassWrapper.java:151)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.ClassesProcessor.initWrappers(ClassesProcessor.java:305)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.ClassesProcessor.writeClass(ClassesProcessor.java:252)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.Fernflower.getClassContent(Fernflower.java:86)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.struct.ContextUnit.save(ContextUnit.java:113)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.struct.StructContext.saveContext(StructContext.java:72)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.Fernflower.decompileContext(Fernflower.java:54)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.BaseDecompiler.decompileContext(BaseDecompiler.java:41)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.IdeaDecompiler.getText(IdeaDecompiler.java:151)
 ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.struct.consts.PrimitiveConstant cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.struct.consts.LinkConstant
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.modules.decompiler.ExprProcessor.processBlock(ExprProcessor.java:563)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.modules.decompiler.ExprProcessor.processStatement(ExprProcessor.java:202)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.rels.MethodProcessorThread.codeToJava(MethodProcessorThread.java:162)
 at org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.rels.ClassWrapper.init(ClassWrapper.java:92)
 ... 81 more
</pre>
```

Comment: Should work. How do you open a .class file, exactly? Please check also if there are any decompiler-related exceptions in Help | Show Log.

Comment: @RomanShevchenko Sorry for late response. Yes, I've checked and get 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.struct.consts.PrimitiveConstant cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.struct.consts.LinkConstant`

I open file just doubleclicking it in project tree(it's in excluded build directory, created by Gradle.)

I've added full(available) stacktrace in question.

Comment: Please check if it works in latest [14.1 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP) - it contains some fixes for very similar exceptions.

Comment: Maven-Re Import did the job for me :)

Answer (score 16):

In my case the problem was that I had installed "Java Decompiler IntelliJ Plugin". Unistall it makes the job.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but I write in Kotlin. I have resolved it by installing `Kotlin to Java decompiler` plugin. Do the following actions:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to open Settings.
2. Plugins -> Marketplace -> input `Kotlin to Java decompiler`.
3. Install the plugin and restart IntelliJ IDEA.
4. Build your project to generate `.class` files.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> in opened `.kt` or `.class` file to see its decompiled Java code.

---

**UPD.** Also you can decompile Kotlin to Java without the plugin.
Go to `Tools` -> `Kotlin` -> `Show Kotlin bytecode`. In the opened tab click to the `Decompile` button. But the plugin is more handy, anyway. :)